# Javascript functions not fetching data on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with the code I have provided below and I'm new to Javascript and Jquery.  What the code is supposed to do is on load it fetches a number for "unread notifications" then places that number in a div called notes_number.  Then it should read the number from notes_number and depending on if the number is more than 0 it will show the div called notes_signal.

I do this on load, every 5 seconds, and then whenever the notifications button is pressed.  The code isn't working because on load it doesn't put a number in the notes_number div.  Also the other occurrences aren't working.  At one point I thought it was working but now I can't figure out what's up.  Here's the code:

```
//THIS IS TO CHECK WHEN THE PAGE COMES UP
$("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML > 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "";
}

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML == 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "none";
}


//THIS IS TO CHECK EVERY 5 SECONDS
window.setInterval(function(){
$("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML > 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "";
}

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML == 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "none";
}
}, 5000);



//THIS IS TO CHECK WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).show();

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?page=<? echo $page; ?>");
});



$("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML > 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "";
}

if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML == 0){
var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
elem.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function checkNotes() {
    $.get( "getnumber.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#notes_number" ).text( data );
        if ( parseInt(data) > 0 ) {
            $('#notes_signal').show();
        } else {
            $('#notes_signal').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

And call it on load, on interval and on button click.

Comment: Is there a way to hide #notes_signal automatically and show it if needed?  Because right now it'll show for half a second then the code kicks in to hide it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: in your CSS put `#notes_number {display: none;}` that will hide it in the first instance

Comment: Create CSS rule `#notes_signal { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.get` in your instance

```
var load = $.get('getnumber.php');
```

Comment: you mean instead of `$("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");`?

Comment: Because the problem of the question is that the request is asynchronous, you should explain what `$.get(...)` returns and what should be done with that result.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous, which means that

`if(document.getElementById("notes_number.....` will run before

`$("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");` is completed.

So you have to use a call back like this:

```
 $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php",function(){
     if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML > 0){
        var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
        elem.style.display = "";
        }

        if(document.getElementById("notes_number").innerHTML == 0){
        var elem = document.getElementById("notes_signal");
         elem.style.display = "none";
       }
  });
```

Also I'm not sure that this will work `elem.style.display = "";`

Try `'elem.style.display = "block";` instead

Comment: `=""` removes the value that was set directly to the element, so it will have the value that results out of the matchig css rules again.